# How to edit default syntax, adding new keyword, to Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I hope the Sublime Text 2 syntax highlighting system to support new C++11 keywords, such as `constexpr`.

However, I did not figure out how to achieve it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit this file:

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/C++/C.tmLanguage`

Go to approx. line 55 and add `constexpr` to the list

```
     <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\b(const|extern|register|restrict|static|volatile|inline)\b</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>storage.modifier.c</string>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a Sublime Text 2 question, but when I tried googling this for Sublime Text 3 I came across this post, so I thought I'd mention that Sublime Text 3 has its own system (docs [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html) and [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html)), and as mentioned by user [lthreed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3330202/lthreed) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184605/cloning-a-sublime-text-3-highlighting-syntax-definition), you can use the package [PackageResourceViewer](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to look at the source of Sublime Text's pre-packaged syntax definitions (and then copy/paste them into your own syntax for editing).