# Creating & intsalling a simple .sublime-syntax file for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to define a *very basic* `.sublime-syntax` syntax-highlight file for Sublime Text 3.

I'm basing it on the first example in the [Sublime Text 3 official documentation on Syntax Definitions](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html):

```
%YAML 1.2
---
name: Z
file_extensions: z
scope: source.c

contexts:
  main:
    - match: \b(if|else|for|while)\b
      scope: keyword.control.c
```

This file is `/Users/justin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/z.sublime-syntax`

(I left the scopes as `.c` because I thought maybe the ST3 "theme" (e.g. Monokai) wouldn't know how to color "keyword.control.z".)

I restart Sublime Text 3 but in the lower-right language selection, no option for "Z" appears.

**What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to ask Sublime if there was a parsing problem? How should I debug this?**

Note: I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184605/cloning-a-sublime-text-3-highlighting-syntax-definition) article,
which describes TextMate-based syntax files, but that method is out-dated since ST3.

Comment: Your example works for me; you may want to double check the file name and path just to be sure (my Mac wanted to save it as a `.yaml` file). Also, the list of available syntaxes probably requires scrolling in the menu, which is easy to overlook.

Comment: Thanks. I uninstalled Package Control (by deleting anything related to Package Control from `/Users/justin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/*`)  and now it works.