# How to create simple Sublime Text 3 custom syntax definition

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text build 3126 on a Windows machine, and I'm trying to follow the steps in [this documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) for creating a very simple syntax definition file. Here is the example given:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
name: Z
file_extensions: z
scope: source.c

contexts:
  main:
    - match: \b(if|else|for|while)\b
      scope: keyword.control.c
```

This doesn't work for me in the same way as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41816312/7542960): no option for this custom definition appears under View > Syntax. The original poster seemed to resolve their issue, but I tried to uninstall and reinstall all of ST3 and related files, but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: where did you save it? if you save the file in `Packages/User/`, it might appear under the `User` submenu. i.e. View -> Syntax -> User -> Z.

Comment: I saved it under that folder as Z.yaml, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: you need to give it a `.sublime-syntax` extension instead of a `.yaml` one

Comment: That worked! I just manually renamed the extension. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to note here:

1. The file extension must be `.sublime-syntax` for ST to treat it as a syntax definition. Using `.yaml` won't work.
2. If you save the file in a folder that already contains a syntax definition, a submenu will be created with the name of the folder, and the syntax will be under that. i.e. if you have one syntax definition in `Packages/User/`, and then save another one, both of them will then appear under the User submenu instead of the main syntax list i.e. View -> Syntax -> User -> Z. Note that you can also use the command palette to find a syntax definition by typing `Set Syntax:`

Comment: This is very helpful, especially the second note about multiple definitions. Thank you so much!